# Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in my build.sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-flink

```
Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/Users/uvps222/Downloads/project/}:
\[error\]    org.apache.flink:flink-runtime \_2.12, \<none\>
\[error\]    org.apache.flink:flink-queryable-state-client-java \_2.12, \<none\>
```

Here's my code snippet

```scala
val scalaLangVersion = "2.12.1"
val flinkVersion = "1.14.6"
val flinkspectorVersion = "0.9.4"

transitiveClassifiers in Global := Seq(Artifact.SourceClassifier)
conflictManager := ConflictManager.latestRevision

lazy val testFlinkDeps = Seq(
"io.flinkspector" % "flinkspector-datastream_2.12" % flinkspectorVersion,
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-test-utils" % flinkVersion
)

val `flink-connector-kafka` = "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion
val `flink-connector-cassandra` = "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-cassandra" % flinkVersion
val `flink-avro` = "org.apache.flink" % "flink-avro" % flinkVersion
val `flink-metrics-dropwizard` = "org.apache.flink" % "flink-metrics-dropwizard" % flinkVersion
val `flink-parquet` = "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-parquet" % flinkVersion
val `flink-hadoop` = "org.apache.flink" % "flink-s3-fs-hadoop" % flinkVersion

val `flink-streaming-scala` = "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion
val `flink-clients` = "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flinkVersion
val `flink-optimizer` = "org.apache.flink" % "flink-optimizer" % flinkVersion
val `flink-runtime-web` = "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-runtime-web" % flinkVersion
dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-runtime" % flinkVersion classifier "tests" exclude("org.apache.flink", "flink-runtime")
```

I have tried adding conflictManager, tried to override dependency too

But still getting the same error on sbt clean assembly
sbt version is 0.13.11

Can anyone help resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Flink dependencies as of 1.14 don't have Scala suffixes anymore, but you're explicitly specifying a Scala version for the dependencies.